# How can I create a Linear Regression Model from a split dataset?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression

I've just split my data into a training and testing set and my plan is to train a Linear Regression model and be able to check what the performance is like using my testing split.

My current code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Dataset.csv')
df['split'] = np.random.randn(df.shape[0], 1)
split = np.random.rand(len(df)) <= 0.75
training_set = df[split]
testing_set = df[~split]
```

Is there a proper method I should be using to plot a Linear Regression model from an external file such as a .csv?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use scikit-learn, here's an approach using [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()

X_train, y_train = training_set[x_vars], training_set[y_var]
X_test, y_test = testing_test[x_vars], testing_test[y_var]

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Depending on whether you need more descriptive output, you might also look into use `statsmodels` for linear regression.

Comment: I'm getting an error telling me that x_vars (and therefore I assume y_var) is not defined?

Comment: Yes... `x_vars` should be a list of your independent variables, and `y_var` should be either a list or string of your dependent variable...